# In ASP.NET 5 type projects how to load file attached to the project

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to load some file in ASP.NET 5 type integration tests project. In the classic .NET I would use the following code:

```js
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var a = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetName().Name +
            "." + "Resources" + ".myfilename");
```

How would you do it in ASP.NET 5?

Comment: The same code should apply in your test project. What is happening that makes you question it?

Comment: it doesn't work. There is no way in ASP.NET 5 even "embed" resource to the project..

Comment: `project.json` has optional `"resource"` section, which allows to specify files, which will be included during compilation. The default value is  `compiler/preprocess/resources/` (see [the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#including-excluding-files)). You can create such directory structure and lace your embedded files here or to add `"resource"` section with the path to embedded files. You can use `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` to get the resources like you did before.

Comment: @Oleg thanks! I've added ""resource": "compiler/preprocess/resources/**/*;Resources/**"" to project.json and it works!!! Perhaps, you could move you comment to the question answer section?

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project.json` has optional `"resource"` section, which allows to specify the files, which will be included during compilation. The default value is `compiler/preprocess/resources/` (see [the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#including-excluding-files)). You can create such directory structure and place your embedded files under `compiler/preprocess/resources/` or to add `"resource"` section with the path to your embedded files. You can use the same code as before (`assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` to get the resources).

Comment: resource is deprecated. You should use buildtoptions\embed instead.